Displaying Multiple Entry Product Metaobjects in Shopify
Metaobject Display Issue: Single vs. Multiple Entries"
I have a question regarding product-related metaobjects. I've created a metaobject that is linked to a product, and I'm able to display it using this syntax: {{ product.metafields.custom.test_avis.value.title }}. This works because it's a metafield with a single entry for each product.
However, I also have another metaobject named "avis_produit" which has multiple entries for a single product. Unfortunately, I'm unable to display it using the code: {{ product.metafields.custom.avis_produit.value.client }}. How can I go about displaying it correctly?

You can use for loop to get the values like below,
      {% for avis_produit in product.metafields.custom.avis_produit.value %}

            <div>
              {{ avis_produit.client }}
            </div>

      {% endfor %}

If you need any specific value then you can use "assign", "capture" and conditional statements as per you need
